# Visual Studio SQL Server Insert Statement

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

This is my Trigger. The first two UPDATE Statements work but, the UPDATE Student does not work.

```
 "UPDATE Student SET PointsAccumulated = PointsAccumulated + @Points
            Where @StudentID = StudentID"


CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Attendance]
After insert 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EventID int
    Declare @StudentID nchar
    DECLARE @Points int

    SELECT @EventID=EventID from inserted
    SELECT @EventID = EventID, @Points = Points from Event
    SELECT @StudentID = StudentID from inserted

    Update Event SET Attendance = Attendance + 1 
        WHERE @EventID = EventID

    UPDATE Attendance SET Points = @Points
        Where @EventID = EventID

    UPDATE Student SET PointsAccumulated = PointsAccumulated + @Points
        Where @StudentID = StudentID
```

THE SOLUTION that worked for me from HLGEM :

```
    Update E
    SET Attendance = Attendance + 1 
    FROM  Event  E
    JOIN Inserted I ON i.eventid = e.eventid


    UPDATE A 
    SET Points = e.points
    FROM Attendance  a
    JOIN Event  E ON a.EventID = e.EventID
    JOIN Inserted I ON i.EventID = e.EventID


    UPDATE S
    SET PointsAccumulated = PointsAccumulated + e.points
    FROM Student S 
    JOIN  Inserted I ON i.studentID = s.studentID
    JOIN Event  E ON i.eventid = e.eventid
```

Lessons Learned:
      In SQL Server, it is never appropriate to use a variable (other than a table variable) to grab what was changed in the table in a trigger as they do not work row-by row like triggers in some other databases 
     --HLGEM

Comment: is it producing any errors or just not updating? Can you make sure that Where @StudentID = StudentID returns a result.

Comment: There are no errors

Comment: you are setting Points variable from the Event table with no where condition. My psychic guess is that Points doesn't contain what you think it contains. With no where clause it will be set to the value of one of the records in the table...which one...who knows!

Comment: Any sql server trigger that expects only one record in inserted or deleted is incorrect. Triggers do not operate row by row and it must be planned that there will be times when these pseudo tables will have multiple rows. NEVER set the value of a field in inserted to a variable which can contain only one value. You should be using joins to inserted or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not tested, but I think this is what you need:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [Trigger]
ON [dbo].[Attendance]
After insert 
AS
BEGIN



    Update E
    SET Attendance = Attendance + 1 
    FROM  Event  E
    JOIN Inserted I ON i.eventid = e.eventid


    UPDATE A 
    SET Points = e.points
    FROM Attendance  a
    JOIN Event  E ON a.eventid = e.eventid
    JOIN Inserted I ON i.eventid = e.eventid


    UPDATE S
    SET PointsAccumulated = PointsAccumulated + e.points
    FROM Students s 
    JOIN  Inserted I ON i.StudentID = e.StudentID
    JOIN Event  E ON i.eventid = e.eventid
```

Note that this fixes the incorrect first two updates as well. When writing SQL Server trigger, you must assume there will be more than one record in inserted or deleted. **Further, you need to test the trigger by deliberately making sure that multiple records were affected by the initial insert or update.** It is irresponsible to create a trigger with the assumption that only one record at a time will ever be inserted, updated or deleted. ANd if you don;t test for the behavior like that, you will have a trigger that creates a data integrity disaster as almost all tables eventually have a multiple record insert/update or deletion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a deep look:

First: You're assigning twice @EventID, from inserted and from Event table

```
SELECT @EventID=EventID from inserted
SELECT @EventID = EventID, @Points = Points from Event
```

Second: I suppose you would use some key reading the Event table

```
SELECT @Points = Points from Event "WHERE EventID = @EventID"
```

Then, @Points maybe has no value due this last sentence has not read anything.

Comment: While you comments are correct about some of what is wrong, you have not fixed the worst error which is assuming inserted will only have one record. In SQL Server, it is never appropriate to use a variable (other than a table variable) to grab what was changed in the table in a trigger as they do not work row-by row like triggers in some other databases...

Comment: Hi @HLGEM, Thanks, I know, but was trying to fix the question. I have an old database with a lot of triggers  and I can assure you that is a a big headache. Personally I prefer to deal with stored procedures, even better than use a business layer in the code.

Comment: Personally I prefer triggers because there are many actions that happen to databases outside the application code.